# Plugin Architecture - One host with many Pipeline folders

Tags: plugins

We currently have an application that is a plugin host, thus having the "Pipeline" folder in it's application directory. All of the plugins that are managed through this host are plugins relating to a windows service that is running, and that windows service is basically for managing one county for the purpose of this example.

What we want to achieve is to be able to install multiple instances of this windows service and to manage each of these through the host application. Our original thought was to have several "Pipeline" folders, one for each county which manages it's instance of the windows service but I don't see how we are going to do this since it seems like the "Pipeline" folder naming convention is set in stone and there is no way to dynamically point your application to a specific "Pipeline" folder.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I always dig up the answer after posting...

There is a parameter on the FindAddIns method used to pass the pipeline root. This should work just fine.